# how to replace NULL value during insertion in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

my table looks like this

```
+--------+--------+--------------+--------------+
| CPI_id | Weight | score_100_UB | score_100_LB |
+--------+--------+--------------+--------------+
|    1.1 |     10 |          100 |           90 |
+--------+--------+--------------+--------------+
```

while executing the insert query the table should look like

```
+--------+--------+--------------+--------------+
| CPI_id | Weight | score_100_UB | score_100_LB |
+--------+--------+--------------+--------------+
|    1.1 |     10 |          100 |           90 |
|    5.5 |     10 |         NULL |           93 |
+--------+--------+--------------+--------------+
```

but NULL values should be replaced by 100.
I also tried using trigger.I couldn't get.

thanks in advance

Comment: Alter table and add a default value to that column. Will work if column value not passed, but not if NULL is explicitly specified.

Comment: In addition to the answers given below, you could also handle `NULL` values in your app layer, and replace them there with appropriate substitutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MySQL use:

```
insert into table values (CPI_id , Weight ,IFNULL(score_100_UB ,100), score_100_LB )
```

or:

```
insert into table values (CPI_id , Weight ,COALESCE(score_100_UB ,100), score_100_LB )
```

SQL Server:

```
insert into table values (CPI_id , Weight ,ISNULL(score_100_UB ,100), score_100_LB )
```

Oracle:

```
insert into table values (CPI_id , Weight ,NVL(score_100_UB ,100), score_100_LB )
```

Answer (score 1):

Alter your table and set the field `score_100_UB` to have some default value  like below

```
 ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY score_100_UB INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 100;
```

After this, whenever you try to insert a NULL value in this column, it will be replaced by 100

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```html
select E.emp_name as Employee, ISNULL( M.emp_name,'No Manager') as Manager
from Employee_Test_salary4 E
left join Employee_Test_salary4 M
on E.report_manager = M.report_manager

or

select E.emp_name as Employee, COALESCE( M.emp_name,'No Manager') as Manager
from Employee_Test_salary4 E
left join Employee_Test_salary4 M
on E.report_manager = M.report_manager

or

select E.emp_name as Employee, CASE WHEN  M.emp_name IS NULL THEN 'No Manager' ELSE M.emp_name END as Manager
from Employee_Test_salary4 E
left join Employee_Test_salary4 M
on E.report_manager = M.report_manager
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you're using a query then use **ISNULL()** function

```
insert into table values (CPI_id , Weight ,ISNULL(score_100_UB ,100), score_100_LB )
```

Comment: It shows an error  Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'

Comment: try changing ISNULL to IFNULL. what database you're using?

Comment: i am using mysql only